# php sql query statement for total

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get total from a stock table from my database.

I have data as follows:

```
Name     Quantity    Type
A        12          add
B        10          add
A        3           sub
B        4           sub
```

Now I want to calculate total quantity as add refers addition and sub refers subtraction. Output must be like:

```
Name     Quantity    
A        9         
B        6
```

I have used following:

```
        $this->db->select('stock.Name,sum() quantity as tot');
        $this->db->from('stock');
        $this->db->group_by('stock.Name');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

Comment: you have no questions marked as solved and you come back asking for more help? start by accepting answers where solutions were so gracefully provided

Comment: this is obviously CI syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` to determine if the quantity needs to be added or subtracted:

```
select name,
    sum(case 
            when type = 'add'
                then quantity
            when type = 'sub'
                then - quantity
            end) quantity
from your_table
group by name;
```

Note that this will not honor any operation other than add and sub, which should be a desired case.

Answer (score 4):

```
select name, sum( case when type = 'add' then quantity else -quantity end) as total 
from my_table 
group by name
```

Comment: you should do like I do and visit previous questions from the OP's ;-) sorry to say but this may not see the "green" light of day

Comment: @sangam - Are all of you previous questions unanswered?

Comment: @scaisEdge [See this comment I left the guy...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470612/php-sql-query-statement-for-total/42470635?noredirect=1#comment72081906_42470612) it will shed more light ;-) or there's no pleasing the guy.

Comment: Seems that the OP don't  know the rules or that he know don't behave  fair ..  .. than  i can try sending a proper advice ..

Comment: @GurV I think unanswered

Comment: @Fred-ii- - See ...  :D

Comment: @GurV yeah, there's no pleasing them, so it seems.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   . thanks  for the adivice related  to the OP  ,,, I think he deserves the same support that he reserves to mark the answers he has previously received .. I had not noticed when I would not respond even to this ..

Comment: thanks for the help guys I have accepted so many answer for my previous questions

Comment: @scaisEdge It all has to do with being of good faith and returning the favor. Kind of like the *"Scratch my back and I'll scratch yours"* type of thing. Or the "Golden Rule" or the "Do onto others what you'd have done to you" or "being a good neighbour" *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii-You are always fair and correct .. I like how you behave .. I really appreciate people who behave so .. I hope your passion for growing catcti go in the best way